# Insert data into oracle with spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark to insert data into oracle,but I hit a problem:

There are several tasks/partitions that write data to oracle in parellel， each task do its own part:

- Obtain the connection
- open the transaction
- insert the data
- commit the transaction
- rollback if task fails

What if some tasks succeed,while one task fail, which means that partial data are inserted while some data are not.

That is, I want to rollback if there is task fails.

Following is the sample code:

```
object SparkJdbcOracle {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[4]").appName("SparkJdbcOracle").getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(0 until 100, 4).foreachPartition(partitionIterator => {
      val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc connection")
      try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false)
        val stmt = conn.createStatement()
        partitionIterator.foreach(i => {
          stmt.addBatch(s"insert into A(id) values ($i)")
        })
        stmt.executeBatch()
        conn.commit()
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => {
          conn.rollback()
          throw e
        }
      }


    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Spark natively exposes a JDBC connector. Are you using that?

Comment: @stefanobaghino I attached the code that I am using to do the insertion

Comment: Probably you could write everything to a staging table while also keeping track of failed tasks, having a second step where you save the staging table to its final destination only if you recorded no failures in the staging phase. It's kind of a DIY 2PC approach.

Comment: @stefanobaghino Thanks you， I would try, thanks!

Comment: @Tom Did you find a solution to this. I have an exactly same use case where i am struggling with number of INSERTs to Oracle. Whats the performance numbers you are able to achieve

Comment: @SandeepShetty I use an additional column, named batch_no and insert with the same batch no in different partitions(tasks), after the insertion wirte succeeds, I update another table to save the latest batch_no